# Adding animated smiley to range slider knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to add an animated smileys to the knob of the range slider however I'm unsure if there is a way I can do this.

Here is what I'm working with:

```js
var emojis = ['','','','',''];

$("input").mousemove(function(){
 var i = $(this).val();
 $(".emoji").html(emojis[i]);
});
```

```css
.rate {
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 ouline: thin solid lightgray;
}
.emoji {
 font-size: 120px;
 height: 170px;
 line-height: 170px;
}

input {
 cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rate">
     <div class="emoji"></div>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="4" step="1">
 </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is adding the smiley to the knob that changes when sliding.

Comment: The following link might be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_rangeslider

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is yes you CAN add emojis but there's a lot of stuff to pay attention to.

1. You're basically removing all the `range input` system styling and replacing it with your own custom styling.
2. The CSS to do this styling is DIFFERENT across all the major browser rending engines (Webkit, Mozilla, MS) so it's a lot of work.
3. Because each render engine is different there's a very good chance that it won't work correctly in some browsers (make sure you're ok with how it fails).
4. As far as I can tell, you can't add `utf-8` text to the slider knob. So you'll need a background image or possibly an SVG of each emoji.

**Here's an example of everything you need from a CSS standpoint for different browsers:**

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 7.8px 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: rgba(48, 113, 169, 0.78);
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0.9px 0.9px 1px #000031, 0px 0px 0.9px #00004b;
  border: 1.8px solid #00001e;
  height: 27px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: rgba(54, 126, 189, 0.78);
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: rgba(48, 113, 169, 0.78);
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0.9px 0.9px 1px #000031, 0px 0px 0.9px #00004b;
  border: 1.8px solid #00001e;
  height: 27px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: rgba(42, 100, 149, 0.78);
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: rgba(48, 113, 169, 0.78);
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0.9px 0.9px 1px #000031, 0px 0px 0.9px #00004b;
  border: 1.8px solid #00001e;
  height: 27px;
  width: 26px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 11.4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: rgba(48, 113, 169, 0.78);
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: rgba(54, 126, 189, 0.78);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

When I get a few more minutes, I'll edit this example with some images. But basically I suggest adding a `background-image` to the `-thumb` pseudo-element.

**At the end of the day, you might be better off building a full javascript solution and forgetting about the HTML5 range input entirely**

Comment: Just add background-image: url(https://openmoji.org/data/color/svg/1F60B.svg); (although you might want to download the resource and serve it from your own server and not openmoji.org)